# Can I apply facets on the entire solr result instead of the filtered solr result?

Tags: filter, solr, facet

Let's say I have a collection of solr documents:

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'shirt', 'brand': 'adidas'},
{'id': 2, 'title': 'shirt2', 'brand': 'adidas'},
{'id': 3, 'title': 'shirt', 'brand': 'nike'},
{'id': 4, 'title': 'shirt', 'brand': 'puma'}
```

Now if I try to apply faceting on this with `facet.field=brand`, I will get the following

```
{'adidas': 2, 'nike': 1, 'puma': 1}
```

In addition, if I apply a filter `brand:adidas`, I get the following for faceting:

```
{'adidas': 2, 'nike': 0, 'puma': 0}
```

Is it possible to still get the count of documents returned by solr before the filtering happened? I would like to still see `{'adidas': 2, 'nike': 1, 'puma': 1}` regardless of what filters I apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use tagging and excluding filters](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters) as shown in the reference guide.

```
q=yourquery&fq={!tag=brand}brand:adidas&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=brand}brand
```

The `{!ex}` instruction will then exclude any filters matching that tag from the active filters when generating the facet results, allowing you to keep the complete set of brands matching the query available as facets.